# Is it ok to throw exception inside the implementation of "boolean isValid(T value, ConstraintValidatorContext context);"

Tags: java, spring, lombok

```
public class validateClassName implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateCustomInterfaceName, BeanRequest > {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(BeanRequest bean, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if ((!bean.property1() && StringUtils.isBlank(bean.property1()))) {
            throw new BadRequestException(ContentConstants.INVALID_REMARK);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { validateClassName.class })
public @interface ValidateCustomInterfaceName{
    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

With the above code is it ok to return Check Exception with the usage of @SneakyThrows?

Comment: Shouldn't that just return false instead of throwing?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for you to throw an exception here. Rather you could disable the default error messages sent ```context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();``` and you can then supply your own messages. Example: 

```context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("invalid remark.").addPropertyNode("property1").addConstraintViolation();```

Comment: Has to write more boilerplate code when try to set own message. So, I tried with above solution and it is working. But want to know what are the cons and don't know this solution align with future release